# Echo Ordered List from Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

How do I make this code echo the data (4 questions) from mySQL database in an ordered fashion so for example.. 1. 2. 3. 4. etc. I basically want the 4 questions to have a question number!

This is my code:

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM NI ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
  echo '<ol>' . '<li>' . $data['Question'] . ' (100)' . '<br>' . '</li>' . '</ol>';
}
```

For some reason my code is echoing the number 1 beside each question!

Comment: Is there any id field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
your query here
    $i=0;

    echo '<ol>';
    while(your given conditions){
    echo "<li>";
    echo $i++." ".$data["question"];
    echo "</li><br>";
    }
    echo '</ol>';
```

Comment: Calculating enumerations within an ordered list? Really?

Answer (score 0):

You should put all items in the `<ol>...</ol>`:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM NI ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");

// Did we actually find anything?
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
  echo '<ol>';
  while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
    echo '<li>' . $data['Question'] . ' (100)' . '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ol>';
}
```

If you wrap each item in `<ol>...</ol>` the enumeration will always start at 1.

A general note: Stop using `mysql_*()` functions. They are deprecated and outdated. Start using `mysqli_*()` instead.